# Testing methods each with a different setup/teardown

Tags: python, testing

I'm testing a class, with many test methods. However, each method has a unique context. I then write my code as following:

```
class TestSomeClass(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_a():
        with a_context() as c:
            pass

    def test_b():
        with b_context() as c:
            pass

    def test_c():
        with c_context() as c:
            pass
```

However, the context managers are irrelevant to the test case, and produce temporary files. So as to not pollute the file system when the test fails, I would like to use each context manager in a setup/teardown scenario.

I've looked at nose's `with_setup`, but the docs say that is meant for functions only, not methods. Another way is to move the test methods to separate classes each with a setup/teardown function. What's a good way to do this?

Comment: The defining characteristic of the python `with` syntax is that it calls both `__enter__` and `__exit__` giving opportunity to both setup and tear down. Why is this not sufficient?

Comment: I don't want to "pollute the file system when the test fails". The next test run can also break when this happens.

Comment: How about `def tearDown(self):`???

Comment: I want to test methods *each with a different setup/teardown*.

Comment: I just tested it and `__exit__` gets called even when an exception is raised or the program exits. I still don't understand why you can't use that to remove contextual files.

Comment: Because this is a unit test. Apparently, they don't obey this rule.

Comment: I just ran a set of tests myself (cPython 2.7.2), and my results are the same as @AndrewJohnson.  I can't get the __exit__ method not to be called either.

Comment: I don't know what tests you're using, but try the example code.

Comment: Look at my context manager vs yours.  Your lack of finally: is probably what's broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I'm not sure why what you have isn't working.  I wrote some test code, and it shows that the **exit** code always gets called, under the unittest.main() execution environment.  (Note, I did not test nose, so maybe that's why I couldn't replicate your failure.)  Maybe your context manager is broken?

Here's my test:

```
import unittest
import contextlib
import sys

@contextlib.contextmanager
def context_mgr():
    print "setting up context"
    try:
        yield
    finally:
        print "tearing down context"

class TestSomeClass(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_normal(self):
        with context_mgr() as c:
            print "normal task"

    def test_raise(self):
        with context_mgr() as c:
            print "raise task"
            raise RuntimeError

    def test_exit(self):
        with context_mgr() as c:
            print "exit task"
            sys.exit(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

By running that with `$ python test_test.py` I see `tearing down context` for all 3 tests.

Anyway, to answer your question, if you want a separate setup and teardown for each test, then you need to put each test in its own class.  You can set up a parent class to do most of the work for you, so there isn't too much extra boilerplate:

```
class TestClassParent(unittest.TestCase):
    context_guard = context_mgr()
    def setUp(self):
        #do common setup tasks here
        self.c = self.context_guard.__enter__()
    def tearDown(self):
        #do common teardown tasks here
        self.context_guard.__exit__(None,None,None)

class TestA(TestClassParent):
    context_guard = context_mgr('A')
    def test_normal(self):
        print "task A"

class TestB(TestClassParent):
    context_guard = context_mgr('B')
    def test_normal(self):
        print "task B"
```

This produces the output:

```
$ python test_test.py 
setting up context: A
task A
tearing down context: A
.setting up context: B
task B
tearing down context: B
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.000s

OK
```